# aligning multiple items in center for all devices

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the items in the center of the screen horizontally and vertically. However, it doesn't work without specifying width and height so that creates a problem for mobile and desktop view. How do I make it responsive so that it looks to be in the center of the screen in every kind of devices?

```css
.parent-container{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
    <button>
    </button>
    <button>
    </button>
    <button>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I mean you're looking for `translate`

Comment: wouldn't that be a problem for multiple items? @pavel

Comment: Add `body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: @connexo didn't work. it pushes the content onto top

Comment: No it does not. Check DCR's code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a min-height. When the content ist larger than the device's height, the `.parent-container` goes beyond.

```
.parent-container{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100vw;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

Comment: it still shows a scroll bar both horizontally and vertically

Comment: Add `body { margin: 0 }`

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove margin from html and body

```css
.parent-container{
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100vh;
  
}

html,body{
margin:0;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
    <button>
    </button>
    <button>
    </button>
    <button>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: there's still a scroll bar for some reason

Comment: No scrollbar in the example.